# Print window blocked by browser popup blocker

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, popupwindow

I'm trying to display a print dialog where a user can print out an invoice through a button control. The main portion of this code is javascript but I noticed that when I clicked the print button, (on 4 different pc's) the popup blocker in google chrome blocked the print page completely. After I allowed popups it worked fine but it is inconvenient for customers to have to constantly say allow popups. I've looked up another option where supposedly window.createPopup kind of bypasses the browser popup blocker but uses window restrictions. I also do not think the window.createPopup is a method in asp.net. How can I prevent the popup blocker from blocking the print page dialog when any customer from our website goes to print the page since I can't control their browser settings? Is it possible to do so?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function PrintGridData() {
       var prtGrid = document.getElementById('<%=panel22.ClientID %>');
       prtGrid.border = 0;
       var prtwin = window.open('', 'Printpanel22Data', 'left=100,top=100,width=1000,height=1000,tollbar=0,scrollbars=1, status=0,resizable=1');
       prtwin.document.write(prtGrid.outerHTML);
       prtwin.document.close();
       prtwin.focus();
       prtwin.print();
       prtwin.close();       
   }
    </script>
```

and the code behind to call the function

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.[GetType](), "PrintOperation", "PrintGridData()", True)
End Sub
```

Comment: You browser is set to block pop up windows. Add it to trusted sites. Or do not use a pop up window and use CSS Print Media to print what you need.

Comment: I'm asking if there is any way to get around it because of the fact that every customer that purchases something from our website will have the option to print out their invoice. So I want to try to avoid the popup blocker since I can't control the customers browser

Comment: You can detect if the pop up window was blocked, but you are better off with CSS Print Media. Simple as adding a new stylesheet and hiding the content you do not want printed.

Comment: Is there a way to still display a print preview or at least display print options to the user when they click the button while using CSS Print Media?

Comment: When you fire `window.print()` that should come up.

Comment: Ok Thanks for your help, I was struggling to figure out how to dialog would be displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A long time ago I had to deal with something like this. I wound up abandoning the popup window to print and just used print styling in my CSS file. Yeah, it's a lot more work, and you're going to use a lot of paper to test it, but I had to cater to users who hated popups.

The only other way to pop a window that I know of is a target="_blank" in the anchor tag...

Comment: before I even look into this, how does print styling with CSS work? Do you call a .css file on a button click?

Comment: You add an @media print { } directive in our stylesheet (or set it up as a separate stylesheet file if you want) and apply your styling in there. You can view it in Print Preview without printing. It's only applied during the print operation, so your display styling isn't affected.

Comment: So I would need to somehow call a print function for this @media print{} to be called? How would I get to the print screen from my button click

Comment: Javascript has a Print method - or the user can hit FIle -> Print or CTRL+P (however they launch the print operation isn't important - the style is applied automatically when it's done) You don't have to worry about this, you get it free from the browser.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help, I am going to give this a try and see if I can manage to get it working.

Comment: Setting it up is a bit of work, but once you do it it's actually a lot easier

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
function PrintDiv() {
            var contents = document.getElementById("dvContents").innerHTML;
            var frame1 = document.createElement('iframe');
            frame1.name = "frame1";
            frame1.style.position = "absolute";
            frame1.style.top = "-1000000px";
            document.body.appendChild(frame1);
            var frameDoc = frame1.contentWindow ? frame1.contentWindow : frame1.contentDocument.document ? frame1.contentDocument.document : frame1.contentDocument;
            frameDoc.document.open();
            frameDoc.document.write('<html><head><title>DIV Contents</title>');
            frameDoc.document.write('</head><body>');
            frameDoc.document.write(contents);
            frameDoc.document.write('</body></html>');
            frameDoc.document.close();
            setTimeout(function () {
                window.frames["frame1"].focus();
                window.frames["frame1"].print();
                document.body.removeChild(frame1);
            }, 500);
            return false;
        }
```